# ASP.NET Designer.xx generates 'already contains a definition for' control error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I currently have a project setup for a DotNetNuke module. Within this project I have some user control files, which are versioned with TFS using ASP.NET 4.0 and C#.

Currently, the project will build and run fine with no issues. However, ANY change I make to the front end .ascx files of SOME of the user controls in the project will cause the corresponding .ascx.designer.cs to generate ~14 errors stating the following error:

Error   ##  The type 'ControlClass' already contains a definition for 'SomeControlID'   'Location of ControlName.ascx.designer.cs'

I have not made any other changes to this previously that I could think of that would cause this issues. It just randomly started happening in my project.

I have tried the following:

- Delete .ascx.designer.cs => Choose project => 'Convert to Web Application' to regenerate the designer file. This always results in the same errors being displayed.
- Reset IIS. Delete ASP.NET Temporary files. Manually clean solution and rebuild. This also reproduces the same errors.
- Delete user control from project. Add new user control with same name. Build. Copy in code to new control front and back. Then rebuild. Reproduces the same errors.

To make things weirder, when I tried to determine if this could be some sort of syntax issue I did the following and produced these results:

1. Undo all changes and revert back to working version in TFS.
2. Build the project. No errors everything is fine and builds.
3. Add a space to the end of the front end .ascx file.
4. Build the project. All errors reproduced again.
5. Upon determining that did nothing, hit CTRL+Z just to make sure it
   is back to normal.
6. Rebuild the project. All errors reproduced again.

I am not sure why, but every time this project has a change to a few select user controls, the designer files generate with these errors all of a sudden.

These user controls contain complex controls which contain templates full of other controls, etc... However when building these I had no issues with names being the same in different templates and things like that.

I have run out of ideas and have found nothing else to try by searching this issue online.

Any suggestions??

**EDIT:**
It has been suggested that I just manually delete the extra generated controls so that the project will build. After looking into this more deeply I have two issues with this.

First, this will allow the project to build, but I would have to do this EVERY time I update the ASCX, as after I delete them and make another change the control declarations are back.

Second, while this will allow the project to build without issue. It does not run but instead throws the following runtime error:

The base class includes the field 'btnDelete', but its type (System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton) is not compatible with the type of control (Telerik.Web.UI.RadButton).

This error indicates to me that the 'btnDelete' control that I deleted to test this, which was marked as a 'duplicate' error when building is now marked as the incorrect type.

This I believe is due to the fact that there are multiple 'btnDelete' buttons of different types on the user control that is giving me the error. These buttons are contained within different RadGrid controls for their edit/delete templates.

Answer (score 2):

Want to add in my case for this error and how I solved.

Happened with a legacy project that was being upgraded to visual studio 2010 project. In my case had to convert the .aspx files to "Web Applications" for the generation of designer files. In this case, not too sure on specifically what happened but started to get the error mentioned above. Started looking at the variable but it was not defined more than once in the code behind (.cs), aspx page or any other associated controls.

I started to look at the aspx page headers and that is when I noticed the possible problem. I had 2 files with similar names... iABC.aspx (.cs,.designer)  and ABC.aspx(.cs,.designer) and in the iABC.aspx header, it was inheriting "ABC"...first sign something was amiss. I changed it to the correct setting "iABC" and then decided to check the class name in the code behind, lo and behold, the class name for the iABC.aspx.cs was set to "class ABC" instead of "class iABC".

Once I fixed up the mess, all was good.

HTH

Dave

Comment: I encountered the same issue - legacy application & mess.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like something is trying to add duplicates of your controls to the designer file. VS updates the designer file on every edit you make which is why it happens as soon as you edit the aspx or ascx files. One thing you can do is when the error is thrown, open your designer.cs file and check--my bet is that you will see duplicate declarations. If this is the case, it is probably a bug in whatever library you are using--though I couldn't know for sure without some more information. Delete the duplicates and you should be able to build again. As far as keeping it from happening again, we need to see what is being generated in the designer file.

Comment: Sorry it seems I forgot to mention that when I delete the 'duplicate entries' from the designer file. The project will indeed build correctly, but will not run as it throws an error saying that control does not exist, etc... So this is not a possible solution for me.

Comment: @user1048281, for kicks, try putting the declaration of the controls in question into your code-behind file and deleting it entirely out of the designer file. What happens then?

Comment: I don't think I will be able to try that as the controls in question are all nested within templates of a very complex RadGrid. This did bring up something I didn't think about before though. It appears all of the controls that are having issues are located within the EditItemTemplate/InsertItemTemplate/GridTemplateColumn declarations  of my RadGrid. Which is interesting and could indicate this is a Telerik issue, however I could not imagine why this control has this issue and all of my other similar controls do not.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i had used the same namespace twice in two different classes.

Verify our namespace and the classname once again - make sure the error is not because of duplicate class files.