# Error CS0102 after converting to Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2017, vs-web-site-project, vs-web-application-project

I have inherited an old Web Site Project. In the long run I'm supposed update it a lot but initially I'm just supposed to make it work in a more modern development environment.

Before I started I opened the web site in Visual Studio 2017 made made sure that I could run it from there at all.

then I started reading and follow the instructions on [So you inherited an ASP.NET Web Forms application](https://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2013/12/30/so-you-inherited-an-asp-net-web-forms-application.aspx). When I got to "2. Convert from Web Site Project to Web Application Project" I jumped over to [Walkthrough: Converting a Web Site Project to a Web Application Project in Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983476.aspx) and continued there. As far as I understand I should have something that I could build and run after "Converting the project files". However I get a lot of these errors:

```
Error CS0102: The type 'FOO' already contains a definition for 'BAR'
```

As far as I can see I have two partial class definitions for FOO and both contains a definition for 'BAR'. But I had these before converting the project as well. There are also lots of these errors:

```
Error CS0229: Ambiguity between 'FOO.BAR' and 'FOO.BAR'
```

And also:

```
Error CS0121: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'FOO.BAR()' and 'FOO.BAR()'
```

Has anyone encountered these problems when converting an old Web Site Project to a Webb Application Project and how was this fixed?

Comment: Have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18520433/asp-net-designer-xx-generates-already-contains-a-definition-for-control-error

Comment: @SehaxX I will look at that and see if I can get anything helpful from it.